# Variation of reverse triangle inequality

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

I know from the reverse triangle inequality that for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the following holds:

$ \vert x \vert - \vert y \vert \leq  \vert x -y \vert $

but does also this one hold?

$ \vert x \vert^2 - \vert y \vert^2 \leq  \vert x -y \vert^2 $

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From above, the greatest value of $|x|-|y|=|x-y|$

also $|x|^2-|y|^2$ = $(|x|-|y|)(|x|+|y|)$

for $|x-y|^2$ $\geq$ $|x|^2-|y|^2$

we must have $|x-y|\geq|x|+|y|$

for every $x,y$ which is not always true you can take a example like let $x=3$ and $y=5$

Answer (score 3):

It is incorrect. A counterexample in $\mathbb R$ is

$x=10,~ y=2$:

$|x|^2-|y|^2=96$
$|x-y|^2=64$, hence $96>64$, a contradiction.